# MKMapView delegate's viewForAnnotation method is called but both parameters are nil

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

As the title says the method

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView1 viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
```

is called, both the mapView1 and the annotation are nil

I am adding one annotation in the usual way in the viewDidAppear method:

```
    [mapView addAnnotation:_a];
```

Tried it out with two annotation implementations - custom and standard. Here is the standard annotation use:

```
MKPointAnnotation *_aa=[[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates;
coordinates.latitude=39.281520;
coordinates.longitude= -76.580806;
_aa.coordinate= coordinates;
_aa.title=@"annotation 2";

[mapView addAnnotation:_aa];
```

Comment: What's the value of _a ?

Comment: class that implements the MKAnnotation protocol:  
  
    @interface CustomAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>  
  
I think I am doing it right, because the annotation is shown on the map exactly where expected with the title and subtitle I set

Answer (score 0):

**MapAnnotation.h**

```
     #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
        #import <MapKit/MKAnnotation.h>

        @interface MapAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>
        @property(nonatomic, assign)    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
        @property(nonatomic, copy)      NSString *title;
        @property(nonatomic, copy)      NSString *subtitle;

    -(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)Region withtitle:(NSString *)Title andSubTitle:(NSString *)SubTitle ;
```

**MapAnnotation.m**

```
@implementation EventAtPlacesAnnotation
@synthesize title = _title, subtitle = _subtitle,coordinate = _coordinate;

 -(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)Region withtitle:(NSString *)Title andSubTitle:(NSString *)SubTitle 
{

    self = [super init];
    if(self){
        _title = Title;
        _subtitle = SubTitle;
        _coordinate = Region;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Assigning  value from class where you used map view

```
    CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.56, 90.83);

    MapAnnotation *firstannotation = [[MapAnnotation alloc]initWithCoordinate:newCoordinate withtitle:@"Place 1" andSubTitle:@"Near To empire state"];

[myMapview addAnnotation:firstannotation];
```

Comment: copy pasted your code, created custom map annotation, however the result is the same - nil value for the argument when the viewForAnnotation is called.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out some "magic" was broken somehow while dragging in the UI builder. Re-built the screen and the controller and now everything works as advertised.